# I'm getting an error trying to run powershell script - Unexpected token

Tags: powershell

I found a script online to help me identify unused groups in AD.  Trying to run it gives me an unexpected token error.

```
$_default_log = $env:userprofile + '\Documents\never_used_ad_group_age.csv'

If ($(Try { Test-Path $_default_log} Catch { $false })){Remove-Item $_default_log -force}

(get-adforest).domains | foreach {$_domain = $_

    get-adgroup -LDAPFilter "(&(!(member=*))(!(memberof=*)))" -Properties "msDS-ReplValueMetaData",whencreated,groupscope,groupcategory -server $_domain | `

        where {(!($_."msDS-ReplValueMetaData"))} | select `

        @{name='Domain';expression={$_domain}},name,samaccountname,groupcategory,groupscope,whencreated,`

        @{name='AgeinDays';expression={(new-TimeSpan($($_.whencreated)) $(Get-Date)).days}},isCriticalSystemObject,distinguishedname,`

        @{name='ParentOU';expression={$($_.distinguishedname -split '(?<![\\]),')[1..$($($_.distinguishedname -split '(?<![\\]),').Count-1)] -join ','}} | `
        export-csv $_default_log -Append -NoTypeInformation

}

write-host "Report Can be found here $_default_log"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure why, but if you remove the back-tick after select on the 3rd line and pull the next line back onto it the error goes away.

```
$_default_log = $env:userprofile + '\Documents\never_used_ad_group_age.csv'

If ($(Try { Test-Path $_default_log} Catch { $false })){Remove-Item $_default_log -force}

(get-adforest).domains | foreach {$_domain = $_

    get-adgroup -LDAPFilter "(&(!(member=*))(!(memberof=*)))" -Properties "msDS-ReplValueMetaData",whencreated,groupscope,groupcategory -server $_domain | `

        where {(!($_."msDS-ReplValueMetaData"))} | select @{name='Domain';expression={$_domain}},name,samaccountname,groupcategory,groupscope,whencreated,`

        @{name='AgeinDays';expression={(new-TimeSpan($($_.whencreated)) $(Get-Date)).days}},isCriticalSystemObject,distinguishedname,`

        @{name='ParentOU';expression={$($_.distinguishedname -split '(?<![\\]),')[1..$($($_.distinguishedname -split '(?<![\\]),').Count-1)] -join ','}} | `
        export-csv $_default_log -Append -NoTypeInformation

}

write-host "Report Can be found here $_default_log"
```

Comment: When telling Poweshell the command continues on the next line via a trailing backtick and the next line is empty ... Most of the backticks are superfluous when formatting differently. PowerShell expects a continuation if the last char on a line is a pipe symbol `|` or a comma `,` so no explicit backtick necessary. **IMO** excessive blank lines don't make the code better readable.

Comment: I've seen weirder things but that worked.  Thank you so much!

Comment: Should have thought of that.